# Finding the best indices to merge two(or more) excel sheets on

Tags: excel, merge, duplicates, record-linkage

- The platform I am working on has different sources of data
  collection.
- Sources:
     E-commerce platform,
     Payment Merchants(some bank tie-up),
     In-house loyalty program and
     Customer Demographics
- Now we're trying to solve the Merge and Purge problem. But
  in order to do that we need to integrate the data into one place.
- The column have different names and there is no unique id to merge the data on. We need to create custom keys like Name + DOB + some other criteria.
- We want to automate the process of finding the best keys to merge the data on.
- I have tried looking for research papers targeting this problem but couldn't find much. My only luck has been [Paxata](https://www.paxata.com/blog/merging-multiple-data-sets-or-excel-spreadsheets/)
- Could someone just point me in the right direction as in where to start?

Comment: Power Query. It's made to get data from different sources, clean it up, create unique indices, combine data, and repeat the whole thing with the next dataset at the push of a button.

Comment: Do I need to suggest unique indices as key to merge the data? 
Because the goal right now is the automation of finding complex keys to merge data on.